# How to know where in /dev/ is a USB keyboard loaded?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, udev

To be precise, when you plug in a USB storage device, it is loaded in `sd` something, but where is a usb keyboard loaded in `/dev/`?

Comment: [What do you need it for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Instead of just giving you the cake, I'm going to give you a hint where the cake might be: take a peek into `/sys/bus/usb` and output of `lsusb`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Sami said.

You can also look into the output of dmesg after you just plug a device into the machine. The kernel will log which file node your device is attached to.